# Python 3 scripts opening with Python 2 compiler

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3

All of the scripts that I save in the C:\Python33 folder are opening with my other installation of Python 2.7.

Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean that the script run with python2.7 in command line, then you need to change `PATH` environment variable. so it include python3.3 folder and not python2.7 folder.

look at: [how to change PATH variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

if you speak about double-click openning in windows, then you need to change the default "open-with" program. you can see how to do it here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs

if you speak about IDLE editor, note that you have two IDELS, one for each python version.
(you can see which version it is in the start-up text. for example:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

but, If I understand you last comment right, what you looking for is exactly the answer that was answered here: [Using "Edit with IDLE" with a Python 2.6.5 script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343138/using-edit-with-idle-with-a-python-2-6-5-script)

Comment: Well the program runs with python 2.7 when you click F5 or click run in the editor. It works fine in the command line

Comment: Sorry about that. What I meant was that the open with is set to python 2.7. I am not able to change this even when I go through the dialog. The default compiler remains as python 2.7 even when I try to change it. The solution from that other question helped

Answer (score 2):

Add the line:

```
#! python3
```

at the start of your scripts. See the [Windows launcher documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher).